# Loading iAds in the BannerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can any one tell me how i can load my required iAds in to the BannerView.
Do we have to give some type of URL from which it will load the iAds.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Regards
Abdul Samad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does that, not you. You have to enable iAD Advertising on your app on ITunes Connect to receive adds. You either do that when submitting a new App or Update Application in the Managing Your Apps section.

Comment: Thanx, can u tell me that it requires developer account or i have to manage it through agent account??

Comment: You or your company needs a Developer account and you have to have Admin, Technical or Legal roles to change it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just drag and drop the ad into Interface Builder, Apple does the rest. You won't see live iAds though until you submit your app to the App Store and enable them (it prompts you when uploading).

Comment: Did any of these answer your question? They are all pretty thorough answers so if you wouldn't mind, a lot of us would be thankful if you would take the time to select the most helpful and accept it.