# iAds Mechanism to show iAds

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

i have made a test application that loads apple test ads.
i am wondering how the real time ads will be loaded instead of apple test ads.
What is mechanism for loading the real time iAds. Can anybody help me in the regard.

Regards
abdul Samad

Comment: This question is very similar to the one you just asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118319/loading-iads-in-the-bannerview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [documentation says](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html), it depends on what kind of certificate was used to sign the app:

- Developer build: test ads
- Ad hoc: test ads
- Distribution: live ads

As [Jasarien notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118668/iads-mechanism-to-show-iads/3118973#3118973), iAds will go live on 1 July 2010 so right now I suspect you would not get any ads at all.

Answer (score 5):

The real ads will be loaded with the same mechanism that is used to load the test ads.

On July 1st Apple will "switch on" iAds and they will start appearing in place of the test ads.

Answer (score 0):

You use the Developer Certificate and provisioning profile to build the release version of the app, and enable the ads while uploading to iTunes Connect. Then when people download your app off the App Store they will see the real ads, and you will make the real money. Apple says that Ad-Hoc and in-house distribution will only show the test ads.

Comment: Did any of these answer your question? They are all pretty thorough answers so if you wouldn't mind, a lot of us would be thankful if you would take the time to select the most helpful and accept it.